# Wordpress get_the_author function test not doing anything?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show the by-line of a Wordpress post only when it's a named author. I don't want to show the byline of the admin user.

Here's the code I'm using to attempt this:

`<?php if (get_the_author() != 'admin')?>
    <h3 style="font-style:italic;">by <?php the_author(); ?></h3>
<?php endif;?>`

The behavior I'm seeing, but don't want, is that the page hangs up and displays only the header. It's only when I comment out the two php lines that the h3 content shows.

I've verified that the full string that would make the condition be true is exactly what I'm showing above. I copy/paste it from the view source of the rendered page. I've even tried using the number 1 both as an integer and as a character type for the test, but it still hangs the page.

What might I be doing wrong? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, where the *"page hangs up"* is one of syntax. You are missing a `:` after your `if` statement:

```
<?php if (get_the_author() != 'admin')?>
                                      ^
```

This should fix it:

```
<?php if (get_the_author() != 'admin'): ?> <h3 style="font-style:italic;">by <?php the_author(); ?></h3> <?php endif;?>
```

This is the kind of error that is easily detectable by enabling `error_reporting` and checking your logs, or enabling `display_errors` as well:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I don't know why I keep forgetting that little detail. I wasn't able to enable error messages because, unfortunately, this is a live site with no staging site and the fix needed to be done before I could reconfigure my dev site. thanks for being so patient!

Comment: No problem. :) You should at least turn on error_reporting and log to a file (by default it's the apache error log) in production. You should still disable display_errors, but error reporting should never be disabled, even on production sites.